# Is there a way to query the GraphAPI to find all pages that added my app as a tab?

Tags: facebook, tabs

I've created a Facebook app that is a tab which users can add to their own facebook pages.

I want to display on the main page a list of installers.

Is there a way to find this? Using FQL? GraphAPI?

Thanks in advance,

Rotem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with FQL or the graph api. The only thing I can think of is the tabs connection on the page object, but you need a page token to get it.

I would solve this manually. You can easily get the page id your tab is displayed on from the facebook signed request, and store it in a DB somewhere. Anytime your tab is viewed just add this check and in a short time you will have a full list. Good luck